# How to enable browser back button disabled with js?

Tags: back-button, browser-history

I have an issue like "after user login to the site if he logout then again if he clicks on browser back button then the previous page showing again instead of login page" for this issue I fixed it by using below js code:

```
history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
   history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
});
```

The browser back button issue fixed but after adding the above js code I got new issue i.e. browser back button totally getting disabled, what if user wants to use browser back button to navigate through the site web pages? can anyone please tell me how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if the user is logged in on page loads, else direct those to the login.

Comment: Are you sure that the previous page being shown isn't cache from the browser? This seems like the wrong way to "solve" this.

Comment: I would not recommend disabling the back button. Instead, check your user status if he's logged in or not. If not then redirect him to the login page.

You could use storage to maintain the state of the user and make sure to clear the storage once the user logs out.

Comment: yes I m checking the user status logged in or not, but after user logout the page which user last accessed is showing but if user clicks on any link on that page then it gets to home page which is correct.

Comment: @Lain, how to check if the user is loggin in on page loads? I think I have to do either in jquery or javascript according to you. can u please tell me how to do that?